# Use lambda filter if element is not null otherwise ignore filter

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have a `lambda` that currently returns `1st` row where date matches passed in date, by using `RecordNumber`.

```
ProList 1
    RecordNumber 1
    ProEffectiveDate NULL

ProList 2
    RecordNumber 2
    ProEffectiveDate 2019-03-01

ProList 3
    RecordNumber 3
    ProEffectiveDate 2019-03-01
```

Here is my current code:

```
Predicate<ProList> filteredRow = 
                    it->it.getProEffectiveDate()!=null &&
                    it.getProEffectiveDate().equals(passedInDate);

final ProList minFilteredRow = ProList()
    .stream()
    .filter(filteredRow)                               
    .min(Comparator.comparing(ProList::getRecordNumber))
    .orElse(null);
```

Now, I have to add functionality for if `ProEffectiveDate` is null to simply return first row from the list.
When `ProEffectiveDate` is null, how do I ignore this filter?

Comment: Could you not just create a method to do this, apply the method to the list, and then return the result, where the method does the processing?

Comment: *ProEffectiveDate is null to simply return first row*.. do you mean if any of the `ProEffectiveDate` is `null` just return the first element of the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your logic required is to check *if any of the `ProEffectiveDate` is `null` just return the first element of the list*, based on that you could do a check as :

```
ProList minFilteredRow;
if (proLists.stream().anyMatch(a -> a.getProEffectiveDate() == null)) {
    minFilteredRow = proLists.get(0);
} else {
    minFilteredRow = proLists.stream()
            .filter(filteredRow)
            .min(Comparator.comparing(ProList::getRecordNumber))
            .orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: Note: Assumption used in the answer is also supported by the `Predicate` used to filter the content otherwise.